# optimizing python file related to heapq.nlargest and extend using loop

Tags: python, numpy, extend

my objective is to find a few (=3 in this example) largest values in one list, `fourire`, identify positions in the list, and obtain corresponding (position_wise) values in the other list, `freq`,  so the print out should be like

`2.  27.`
`9.  25.`
`4.  22.`

the attached python is working fine....sort of.

** note that i am dealing with numpy array so index() is not working....

is there way to improve the followings?

```
import heapq

freq    = [  2., 8., 1., 6., 9., 3.,  6., 9.,   4., 8., 12.]
fourire = [ 27., 3., 2., 7., 4., 9., 10., 25., 22., 5.,  3.]

out = heapq.nlargest(3, enumerate(fourire), key=lambda x:x[1])

elem_fourire = []
elem_freq = []
for i in range(len(out)):
    (key, value) = out[i]
    elem_freq.extend([freq[key]])
    elem_fourire.extend([value])

for i in range(len(out)):  
    print elem_freq[i], elem_fourire[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

fourire = np.array(fourire)
freq = np.array(freq)

ix = fourire.argsort(kind='heapsort')[-3:][::-1]

for a, b in zip(freq[ix],fourire[ix]):
    print a, b
```

prints

```
2.0 27.0
9.0 25.0
4.0 22.0
```

If you want to use **heapq** instead of **numpy**, a slight modification of your code above yields:

```
ix = heapq.nlargest(3,range(len(freq)),key=lambda x: fourire[x])
for x in ix:
    print freq[x], fourire[x]
```

results in the same output

Comment: well, you can tell i'am very new to python. this one is so python-ish. i hear that "enumerate" is very slow and try to figure out to get rid of it. thanks very much.